# Sort an array of numbers in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

We are using below code to sort the lines in a file. I gave input linesas below:

> 6 5 1 12 10

But am getting out as below:

> 10 12 1 5 6

I need out as

> 1 5 6 10 12

Is there any way to sort the numeric lines in Inno Setup.

```
procedure SortList(const FileName: string);
var
  I: Integer;
  Files: TStringList;
begin
  Files := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Files.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    for I := Files.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      Files.sort;
    end;
    Files.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    Files.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How many items (numbers) will be in that string list in real ?

Comment: string list will contains N items(numbers).

Comment: This is occurring because you're sorting the values as text.  You will either need to zero-pad the numbers so that they are all the same length, or use `StrToInt` or similar to convert the text to a number before sorting it.  (Note that Inno does not include a generic non-string array sort function, so you will have to write the sorting algorithm yourself.)  It's a fairly unusual sort of thing to need to do in an installer.

Comment: Pity that [`TStringList.CustomSort`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TStringList.CustomSort) isn't published. It could have been very simple task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following Quicksort proc should do the job:

```
//Start is the index of the first item on the list - usually 0
//Stop is the index of the last item of the list e.g. Count - 1
procedure QuickSort(var List: TStringList; Start, Stop: Integer);
var
  Left: Integer;
  Right: Integer;
  Mid: Integer;
  Pivot: integer;
  Temp: integer;
begin
  Left  := Start;
  Right := Stop;
  Mid   := (Start + Stop) div 2;

  Pivot := StrToInt(List[mid]);
  repeat
    while StrToInt(List[Left]) < Pivot do Inc(Left);
    while Pivot < StrToInt(List[Right]) do Dec(Right);
    if Left <= Right then
    begin
      Temp           := StrToInt(List[Left]);
      List[Left]  := List[Right]; // Swops the two Strings
      List[Right] := IntToStr(Temp);
      Inc(Left);
      Dec(Right);
    end;
  until Left > Right;

  if Start < Right then QuickSort(List, Start, Right); // Uses
  if Left < Stop then QuickSort(List, Left, Stop);     // Recursion
end;
```

instead of calling:

```
Files.sort;
```

use the following:

```
 QuickSort(Files, 0, Files.Count - 1);
```

One caveat is that the file contents always have to be valid integers because I have not added error handeling for other cases.

The Quicksort function I used is a modified version of the one found at Torry's Delpi: http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1916